# How do I render a win32 window to an opengl texture?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I want to be able to render a win32 control inside an OpenGL texture. In order to be able to 3d transform it. Specifically I want  to embed Internet explorer to show webpages and video inside a 3D transformed window.

How do I render a win32 window to a texture in a fast enough way (I need to keep 60 fps)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can go about it. In all cases, you will need to fetch a device context (DC) from the target window ([`GetDC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetDCEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144873(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Then, you can either read the pixels directly ([`GetPixel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx)); or blit the contents into your own DC ([`BitBlt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx)) and then access that (e.g. [`GetDIBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144879(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Since you want to "embed" Internet Explorer, and by that you probably mean keeping its window hidden; you will want to consider how to make the above work on windows that are not visible, partially visible, etc. Consider as well your Windows version and/or whether the DWM might be disabled (and therefore the content of a window may not be available). Take a look at [`PrintWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162869(v=vs.85).aspx) to force a `WM_PAINT`/`WM_PRINT`.

One small MSDN guide that can introduce you to all this and has a full example is: [Capturing an Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx).

In any case, you can always go for an alternative solution by embedding some other browser/engine as a library (e.g. [Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework), [Qt's WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-index.html), [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)...).

Comment: PrintWindow was the missing piece. I prefer explorer as is already running in Windows 10. I want to avoid adding another 800 pound gorilla unless absolutely necessary.